# Why does the filament of a lightbulb glow instead of the wires carrying the current?

Tags: electrostatics

How come the wires that carry the current to a lightbulb dont glow but the filament inside a bulb does glow

Comment: Why do you think the wires should glow?

Answer (score 1):

By design a filament has much higher resistance than the wires carrying current to the filament.  Energy dissipated in a circuit is $I^2 R$ where $R$ is the resistance and $I$ is the current.  High conductivity materials ,copper for instance are used in wires carrying current to electrical devices resulting in low energy loss in the wires themselves.  The bulk of the energy is used in the low conductivity filament, causing high heat and light in the filament.